# Render labels in Chart.js line chart (Python/Pycharm)

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, chart.js, linechart

I am trying to create a Chart.js line chart where the labels can be dynamically set by render the labels.

Here is the code in the views.py:

```js
def graph1(request):
    labels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    data1 = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4]
    data2 = [5, 8, 9, 6, 7]
    player1 = 'Paul'
    player2 = 'Lisa'
    return render(request, 'graph1.html', {
        'labels': labels,
        'data1': data1,
        'data2': data2,
        'player1': player1,
        'player2': player2,
    })
```

Here is the html code:

```html
<div id="container" style="width: 100%;">
    <canvas id="line-chart"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    var config = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: {{ labels }},
        datasets: [{
            data: {{ data1 }},
            label: "Player 1",
            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
            fill: false,
            tension: 0
          }, {
            data: {{ data2 }},
            label: "Player 2",
            borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
            fill: false,
            tension: 0
      }
    ]
  },
    };

    window.onload = function() {
      var ctx = document.getElementById('line-chart').getContext('2d');
      window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };

  </script>
```

My graph is showing like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MEIk.png)

Rather than having static labels showing "Player 1" and "Player 2", I would like these to be dynamically set. So maybe first time shown as "Paul" and "Lisa" and next time shown as "Peter" and "Mary" (depending what is read from the database).

I was attempting different options but no luck getting this set by render:

```html
<div id="container" style="width: 100%;">
    <canvas id="line-chart"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    var config = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: {{ labels }},
        datasets: [{
            data: {{ data1 }},
            label: {{ player1 }},
            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
            fill: false,
            tension: 0
          }, {
            data: {{ data2 }},
            label: {{ player2 }},
            borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
            fill: false,
            tension: 0
      }
    ]
  },
    };

    window.onload = function() {
      var ctx = document.getElementById('line-chart').getContext('2d');
      window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };

  </script>
```

Doing it with the code above then the line graph does not show at all.

I appreciate any assistance on getting this to work.  I am a beginner Python/Pycharm developer and this is my first project.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue myself by simply adding quotation marks around the rendered data for the label as seen in this code:

```html
datasets: [{
            data: {{ data1 }},
            label: "{{ player1 }}",
            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
            fill: false,
            tension: 0
          }, {
            data: {{ data2 }},
            label: "{{ player2 }}",
            borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
            fill: false,
            tension: 0
      }
```